# Specify [HttpGet], [HttpPost] or [AcceptVerbs] for the whole controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Many action filters can be specified for the whole `Controller` in ASP.NET MVC, resulting in it being applied to all of the actions in the controller. For example:

```
[Authorize]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    // ....
}
```

means that the `[Authorize]` applies to all of the actions in the controller, which is very convenient.

But when I try to put `[HttpGet]`, `[HttpPost]` or `[AcceptVerbs(...)]` on the controller, the compiler complains that the attribute is only usable for methods (which is right, since they are defined with `[AttributeUsage]` pointing only toward methods).

What if I want to limit all actions in a controller to POST verb only?

My question is:

- Is there any way in the framework to achieve this, without writing my own attribute?
- Why are these attributes implemented this way, not allowing them on controllers?

Comment: I think in most cases, controllers represent a set of related actions which are a mixture of GET and POST, so I can see why this attribute wasn't created to apply to the class level.  That won't stop you from building your own though.  If you're Posting something though, aren't you posting from something that you have to first GET?

Comment: @JasonNesbitt Yes, most of the times. I encountered this when I wanted to add a controller for a web-based API, where I want all methods (actions) to be marked with [HttpPost], cause there's no direct user interaction, and there's no GET requests from the same controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpGet and HttpPost inherits from ActionMethodSelectorAttribute Class, and are valids only for methods. I think that you need create your own attribute.

Answer (score -1):

Custom attribute to solve this:

```
    public sealed class AllowedMethodsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private readonly string[] methods;

        public AllowedMethodsAttribute(params string[] methods) => this.methods = methods.Select(r => r.Trim().ToUpperInvariant()).ToArray();

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext)
        {
            if (!methods.Contains(actionContext.HttpContext.Request.Method))
            {
                actionContext.Result = new StatusCodeResult(405);
            }
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
[AllowedMethods("GET", "PATCH")]
```